# Right ascension of a star and local sidereal time

Tags: observational-astronomy, telescope, amateur-observing

If I'd like to watch star like Betelgeuse that has coordinates - right ascension 05h 55m 10.30536s and declination +07° 24′ 25.4304″.

- If my local sidereal time is 05h 55m 10.30536s does it mean that Betelgeuse crossed my meridian?
- And if I want to track it with right ascension on the telescope I can define it as `LST - RA of a star` take this number and put it on the RA axis of a telescope and see a star?

Comment: LST - RA is better known as the "Hour Angle" of an object. It is 0 when the object is on the meridian, and increases for every hour of RA past that time.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hour_angle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your local sidereal time is 05h 55m 10.30536s, then Betelgeuse is on the meridian. The local sidereal time is always equal to the right ascension of a point on the meridian.